# How can I change the background color of an activity dynamically within the onCreate statement with Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, xml, background, sdk

I would like to know if it is possible to change the background color of an activity dynamically by checking in the onCreate statement if the settings say 'Red' or 'Blue', and then accordingly change the background color of the activity to 'Red' or 'Blue'.

I have found several answers on StackOverflow that looked like they worked for other people, but they don't seem to work for me. Here's a list of things I tried:

1. Using setBackgroundColor() combined with a view.

   ```
   if (settings.getBoolean("Blue", true)) {

   View currentView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.home_screen);
   currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

   } if (settings.getBoolean("Red", false)) {

   View currentView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.home_screen);
   currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

   }
   ```
2. Using setTheme() combined with different styles. This works in a way that I the background of my elements such as TextViews change in 'Red' or 'Blue' instead of the background color of the whole activity.

   ```
   <style name="RedTheme">
       <item name="android:background">@color/redbackground</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/redbackground</item>
       <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/redbackground</item>
   </style>
   ```

   In this case, only android:background seems to change anything, but unfortunately it changes the backgroundcolor of my TextView element.
3. Using getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE), but that also seems to do nothing at all.

Is there anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong or tell me how I can successfully accomplish this?

Great thanks in advance!

---

Added the complete code by request:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    changeTheme();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
}

private void changeTheme() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings, 0);

    if (settings.getBoolean("Blue", true)) {

        View currentView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

    } if (settings.getBoolean("Red", false)) {

        View currentView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, your main layout of `home_screen` should be **FrameLayout**, dont forget to give it some id, i.e. like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreenActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home_screen">

<!-- rest of your UI here -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your `onCreate` create `View` variable and connect it to this layout by **ID**.
From now on your `setBackgroundColor()` should work (below code with small changes works for me - i'm not refering to settings, but i call `changeTheme()` after some time with changed value)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    changeTheme();
}

private void changeTheme() 
{
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings, 0);
    View currentView = (View) findViewById(R.id.activity_home_screen);

    if (settings.getBoolean("Blue", true)) 
    {
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    } 
    else if (settings.getBoolean("Red", false)) 
    {
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, that works! Thanks! In my case I have a home screen with a button to another activity (the settings). When I change the settings from red to blue, it doesn't instantly change the background, but only when I go to another activity and then return. I think that is because the onCreate function is not called again every time. Is there another function that I can use that runs every time the user sees the activity?

Comment: @Thijs93H: You should read topic about Activity Lifecycle i.e. [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
It would be better to call `changeTheme()` from `onStart()`, but to be honset in this shape you can call it from wherever you want...
I was able to run it from few different `AsyncTasks`

Answer (score 0):

Move this from `onCreate` to separate method:

```
private void changeTheme(){

    if (settings.getBoolean("Blue", true)) {
        View currentView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.home_screen);
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    } else if (settings.getBoolean("Red", false)) {
        View currentView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.home_screen);
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }

}
```

and then call `changeTheme()` from `onClick()` or whatever

Comment: I also tried that, but I called the changeTheme() method in the onCreate method. That will crash the app every time it creates the activity, however...